# MyPy's linter showing up error, where's none in logging.disable

Tags: python, logging, mypy, python-typing

[image]

MyPy prints out an error "Argument 1 to 'disable' has incompatible type 'str'; expected 'int'
According to Python's wiki and running the code, everything is fine, but to MyPy, it's not. Am I doing something wrong?

`logging.disable('DEBUG')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logging levels are integers, not strings. They are defined as constants in the `logging` module, which you can import. E.g.:

```py
logging.disable(loggging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Huh! Makes sense. Thanks! :D